# Path connections in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples called 'data' of the form:

```
[('Aaa', 'Bb', '3'), 
 ('Aaa', 'Fffff', '5'),
 ('Aaa', 'Gggg', '4'),
 ('Abb', 'Cddddd', '3'),
 ('Cccc', 'Bb', '1'),
 ('Dddd', 'Cccc', '2')]
```

This data simulates an undirected graph, where there is a connection from 'Aaa' to 'Bb' of size 3.  Because the graph is undirected, it also means that there is a connection from 'Bb' to 'Aaa' of size 3 as well.

I need to show whether or not there is a connection between two inputs that is smaller than 'd' hops.  For example, if the input was 'Aaa', 'Dddd', and 5, the result would return the path Aaa, Bb, Cccc, Dddd becuase there is a path that exists between Aaa and Dddd in less than or equal to 5 hops.  However, if the input was 'Aaa', 'Dddd', and 2, the result would be "no connection".

```
def hop_connection(data, first, second, d):
    count = 0
    netSize = 0
    mapConnections = []

    while (count < d):
        for result in data:


        count = count + 1
```

How can I show that there is a connection from 'Aaa' to 'Dddd' that uses 3 hops, through the path Aaa, Bb, Cccc, Dddd of size 3+1+2 = 6?

Comment: I don't know about the other users, but I have no idea what you're asking. Perhaps put a desired input and output and maybe a small bit of code?

Comment: Find the minimal path between the two nodes with a well know algorithm for that (i.e [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)) and assert if that path is less than the given number of hops (d). Just asume a weight of 1 for each edge.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, this is my solution.

```
def hop_connection(start, end, hops):
    start = ord(start.upper())
    end = ord(end.upper())
    distance = end - start + 1
    if abs(distance) <= hops:
        if distance > 0:
            path = range(start, end + 1)
        else:
            path = list(range(end, start + 1))[::-1]
        print(", ".join(chr(c) for c in path))
    else:
        print("No connection.")
```

See it in action (based on your examples):

```
hop_connection("A", "D", 5)
hop_connection("A", "D", 2)
```

Output:

```
A, B, C, D
No connection.
```

Even more:

```
data = [('A', 'B', '3'), 
        ('A', 'F', '5'),
        ('A', 'G', '4'),
        ('C', 'B', '1'),
        ('D', 'C', '2')]
for item in data:
    hop_connection(item[0], item[1], int(item[2]))
```

Output:

```
A, B
No connection.
No connection.
C, B
D, C
A, B, C, D
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to use this implementation when the tuples contain strings rather than chars? @cdonts I edited my original question to reflect this

Comment: Chars or strings don't matter, @cdonts has just given you a simplified example but it's the same answer if you replace with your strings. In some languages 's' implies a char, but in Python it's just a string of size 1. ' and " are equivalent (as long as they're balanced) in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MilesGillham A problem I'm running into is how to use ord() on a string because the error says it expects a character.

Comment: @CSstudent `ord()` can't be used on strings because it returns the integer `ord`inal of a character. Seeing your edit I can't get how does the string length should affect the *algorithm*...

Comment: @cdonts string length is not involved in the algorithm.  Each string is representing a node, in which I need to find a path between two nodes where the number of 'hops' between nodes is <= d. Thanks.

Comment: @CSstudent I get it, but why `hop_connection('Aaa', 'Dddd', 5)` should result in `Aaa, Bb, Cccc, Dddd`? Why the difference in lengths?

Comment: @cdonts The 5 is saying that there exists a path between node Aaa and Dddd that can be reached in 5 or less 'hops'.  The function then returns a valid path (a path that stretches between Aaa and Dddd across 5 or fewer nodes)

Comment: @CSstudent I'm talking about the results length: Aaa (3), Bb (2), Cccc (4), Dddd (4).

Comment: @cdonts the length of the string makes no difference in the outcome and has no effect on d or the third element in each tuple.  The third element in each tuple is just a weight on an edge of the graph between two nodes (the first and second strings in the tuple).

Comment: @CSstudent Then just use `hop_connection(item[0][0], item[1][0], int(item[2]))` to take the first letter and run the algorithm.

Comment: @cdonts sorry, my example data is making this more confusing than it needs to be.  I edited data again.  The problem is multiple nodes will have the same starting letter.  Data is actually a huge file of different city names and distances.

Comment: @CSstudent Well, this algorithm is based on the positions of the letters (think it as A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 and so on...). In your case, you must have a numeric value linked to each city name so the algorithm can calculate the distance between two of them. I think that's another story. You should probably ask another (and more generally) question.